# use mysql_real_escape_string() but allow names with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql

I use mysql_real_escape_string() to validate all user inputs before I insert them in a sql database.  One of the fields is name, and we've had issues with users with names like O'Reilly.  Is there any way to use mysql_real_escape_string() to block injections but allow these names in the db?

Comment: mysql\_real\_escape\_string() is not for validation.

Comment: Don't understand the question - http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string - this function escapes single quotes. So `O'Reilly` becomes `O\'Reilly`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is most likely that the apostrophes get quoted twice: first by the evil and deprecated in 5.3 [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) and then by `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

What you can do is either [disable magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) or run [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/stripslashes) on your input values **before** feeding them to `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Brief explanation of the problem:

- the user enters `O'Reilly`
- magic quotes automatically turn it into `O\'Reilly`
- the script feeds the string through mysql_real_escape_string() which escapes **both** the backslash and the apostrophe (again) yielding `O\\\'Reilly`
- the query is executed, the quoting is processed and the database understands that you want a backslash **and** an apostrophe since they where both escaped, and records `O\'Reilly`

Comment: This is the right answer. Note that you may have corrupted data in the database at this point, which means that when you do the right thing, you'll get errors. Fix the data.

Comment: troelskn: Why do you think this is the right answer. I don't think Brian gave enough information to be sure of it.

Comment: Robin: the only way `O\'Reilly` can be recorded in the database is if you have double escaping: if you feed the db a "single-pass-escaped" `O\'Reilly` it records `O'Reilly`, if you feed it `O\\\'Reilly` **then** you get the escaped version in the db

Comment: You are right, fix the source of the problem, not the results!

Comment: @MatteoRiva I'd rather not start a new topic but is this right:

`$stadium_name = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stadium_name']));`

There are no slashes and is it still protected when entered into a mysql query?

Comment: @weka nope, one function basically destroys what the other one does

Answer (score 0):

As already mentionned : mysql_real_escape_string is not meant for input validation. If you want to validate inputs, use your own functions or the [filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) from php.

If you have too many slashes added automatically by php, disable magic quotes.

To prevent SQL injection, use parameterized queries with either [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

+1 for using PDO. I've been using PDO in favour of a MySQL class acting as a database abstraction layer for a few months now and it's a breeze.

Traditionally, developers would use the `stripslashes()` function on data before applying a function like `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It's still a good idea to remove slashes from input data, but you can then either use the PDO method for escaping data (`PDO::quote($data)`) or binding the parameter.

Your query block would then look something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (:value1, :value2)";
$smt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$smt->bindParam(':value1', $value1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$smt->bindParam(':value2', $value2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$smt->execute();
$rows = $smt->rowCount(); // returns number of rows affected
```

I hope this helps somewhat. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for more information on PDO in PHP.